# $_REQUEST['url'] is getting wrong url

Tags: javascript, php, url, request

I have a form defined like this:

```
<table>
<form id="myForm" method="post"> 
<tr><td> Item Name: </td><td><input type="text" name="itemname" id="itemname"/></td></tr>
<tr><td> Description:</td><td> <input type="text" name="description" id="description"/></td></tr>
<tr><td> Sell Time:</td><td> <input type="test" name="selltime" id="selltime"/></td></tr>
<tr><td> Price:</td><td> <input type="test" name="price" id="price"/></td></tr>
<tr><td> Image URL:</td><td> <input type="test" name="url" id="url"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" value="Post" name="info" onclick="return post();"></td></tr>
</form>
</table>
```

As you can see, **onclick** it calls the function `post()`. Which in turn reads the file `post.php` and sends it the required parameters (`itemname`,`description`,`selltime`,`price`,**`url`**). And finally they get inserted to some table in a database.

Here's the beginning of the file `post.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();
mysql_connect("localhost","root","password") or die("couldnt connect");
mysql_select_db("mynewdb") or die("couladnt find");
$output = '';
if(isset($_REQUEST['itemname']) && isset($_REQUEST['description'])
&& isset($_REQUEST['selltime']) && isset($_REQUEST['price']) &&
isset($_REQUEST['url'])){
$url = $_REQUEST['url'];
...
?>
```

Problem is `url` is sometimes got wrong. For example if i enter this url: [coca cola](http://www.comax.co.il/Max2000Upload/1443/Prt_Pic%5C1%5C864.jpg)

http://www.comax.co.il/Max2000Upload/1443/Prt_Pic%5C1%5C864.jpg

I get this inserted instead:

http://www.comax.co.il/Max2000Upload/1443/Prt_Pic1864.jpg

Why is that?

**edit:**

As requested, following is the `post()` function:

```
<script>
function post()
{   
    var itemname = document.getElementById('itemname').value;
    var description = document.getElementById('description').value;
    var selltime = document.getElementById('selltime').value;
    var price = document.getElementById('price').value;
    var url = document.getElementById('url').value; 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
    else
    {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        document.getElementById("posted").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","post.php?itemname="+itemname+ "&description="+description+ "&selltime="+selltime
            +"&price="+price+"&url="+url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You left out the most important parts: the `post()` javascript function and what you do with `$url`.

Comment: I added the function code. `$url` get inserted into a database, and if i check the database i can see that the `$url` is inserted wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

The "%5C" stands for a "\" and it might be escaping the following numbers, try to replace them with a "\\", this should keep the backslash in the url.

Comment: Is there a `function` that does that?

Comment: Use php "str_replace": http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php. Here's an example: str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $url).